# Neater way to ignore errors in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

Let's consider any (potentially lengthy) function that can produce an error. For discussion's sake, I'll use `=1/0`. I can ignore the resulting error by using the following formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(1/0),"",(1/0))
```

As you can see, the function (e.g. `1/0`) is typed twice. Is there a neater way to do this?

Comment: Are you trying to igore errors or are you trying to avoid writing a lengthy function multiple times?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Both. For efficiency's sake, I want to avoid repeating code.

Comment: Only in LibreOffice? Or also Excel?

Comment: I am working in LibreOffice. I tagged Excel since I imagined the Q&A would be similar, if not identical.

Comment: With Excel, if you have Office365, you can use the `LET` function. I am not sure that LibreOffice Calc has an equivalent function.

Comment: Oh neat! I see that it assigns variables. I haven't come across an analog in LibreOffice Calc, but maybe there is one.

Answer (score 1):

A user on another forum found the [answer](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/271562/calc-neater-way-to-ignore-errors/?answer=271624#post-id-271624):

> Hello,
>
> check function `IFERROR()`: In your example it would read:
> `=IFERROR(1/0;"")`
>
> See also: [LibreOffice Help - IFERROR](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/scalc/01/04060104.html?DbPAR=CALC#bm_id31470811)
>
> Hope that helps.